# Adding tabs into a TabPane depending on the clicked button

Tags: javafx

I have a file named **Home.fxml** which is a `BorderPane`. This component has buttons on the left and an empty TabPane called `mainTabPane` in the centre. I would like, when a user clicks on any button on the left, to add a tab to `mainTabPane`. I am able to add one tab when one button is clicked. But when I try to do the same for the second button, I get this error:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location not set`

Here is the code for HomeController.java, where all is done:

```
public void initialize(URL loc, Resource Rse) {
    createReportsTab();
    loadCreateItemTab();
}

/*this is the one which works well*/
@FXML
void CreateReportTab() { 
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
    loader.setLocation(ReportsController.class.getResource("gui/Reports.fxml"));
    Parent parent = loader.load(); 
    Tab reportsTab = new Tab("Reporting Engine");
    reportsTab.setClosable(true);
    reportsTab.setcontent(parent);
    mainTabPane.getTabs().add(reportsTab),
}

/*this is the one which produces the error*/
@FXML
void loadCreateItemTab() { 
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); 
    loader.setLocation(AddNewItemController.class.getResource("gui/addNewItem.fxml"));
    Parent parent = loader.load(); 
    Tab newItemTab= new Tab("New Item");
    newItemTab.setClosable(true);
    newItemTab.setcontent(parent);
    mainTabPane.getTabs().add(newItemTab),
}
```

I am confused; why the **Reporting Engine** loads well but the second one is producing that error above?

Here is my project structure in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

All controller classes are in the controllers package and all FXML files are in the GUI package. The main class is in Companion package.

Answer (score 0):

Error suggests that **addNewItem.fxml** is not read. Change:

```
AddNewItemController.class.getResources("gui/addNewItem.fxml");
```

to

```
ReportsController.class.getResources("gui/addNewItem.fxml");
```

, since this path worked for you already.

Comment: This is what someone pointed me to `URL url = getclass.getResource("gui/addNewItem.fxml"); Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url)`that worked well. but `addNewTab.setClosable(true)`  is not working, am not able to close a tab once it is opened. any idea please @Andrzej Pazurkiewicz

Comment: Two ways to do it, either in your FXM where is your TabPane tag add tabClosingPolicy="SELECTED_TAB", or within code yourTabPane.setClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);